# out.println() does not work

Tags: java, jsp

I have homework which I have to use scriptlets in ,
I need to make new line in my jsp page usint out object
I tried to use

```
<%
out.println();
out.newLine();
 %>
```

but both doesn't work !!! I treid to use

```
out.flush()
```

but it doesn't work!!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What is the output?

Comment: it doesn't make new line

Comment: Oh _gawd_, someone's actually **teaching** you to write JSPs with scriptlets? `gag`

Comment: I actually work with JSTL but they said u have to learn scriptlet any way!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps `out.println("<br>");` is what you're after. (Remember that the browser in which you're viewing the jsp-page in, **interprets the output of your script as HTML**, which basically ignores newline characters.)

You can look at the source of the page to see what the jsp-page actually generates.

If you *really* want to see the verbatim output of the jsp-script, you could do

```
out.println("<html><body><pre>");

// ...

out.println("</pre></body></html>");
```

Comment: it works, but I don't think this is the correct way to use java tags1!
I read in more than one turorial that out.println() makes new line.
see here http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jsp/jsp-out-object-methods.html

Comment: It makes a newline.  Use "View source" in your browser.

Comment: `<br/>` will fail HTML validation as it's XHTML and not HTML. If it's HTML you're encoding in then use `<br>`.

Comment: @Steve, ah, ok, thanks for pointing that out. Someone told me to always favour `<br/>` over `<br>`. Never quite understood why though.

Comment: They probably thought that `<br/`> was better because it's valid XML, which is irrelevant if the encoding is HTML.

Answer (score 6):

@Alaa - `out.newLine()` **does** work.  It just doesn't do what you are expecting it to do ... assuming that your JSP is generating an HTML page.

When you use `out.newLine()`, it adds a newline character to the content stream that you are generating.  If you use view source on the page in your web browser you can see the newline character.

But a newline character in an HTML document typically **does not** result in a line break in the displayed page as rendered by a browser.  To get the browser to render line break in the displayed page, you typically<sup>*</sup> need to output a `<br />` element.

<sup>* - Actually, there are other ways to get the visual equivalent of a line break involving CSS, etcetera.  And within a `<pre>...</pre>` a raw newline character *does* get rendered as a line break.</sup>

Comment: I wish these people using JSP/servlets actually took some time to understand HTML first!

Comment: I do understand HTML, but many tutorials on internet mention the same thing about making new line :S!!

Comment: @Alaa - I put it to you that 1) you might be misreading the tutorials, and 2) you should not be treating material in tutorials as definitive ... that's what **specifications** are for; e.g. the HTML specs on the W3C website.

Comment: do u mean that I should rely only on specifications of languages??

Comment: No - I mean that if there is some doubt about what (for instance) some random web tutorial says, you should check the specification.  Stuff on the web is often incomplete, inaccurate, misleading or just plain wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Remember the JSP code is outputting HTML.  The HTML will then be rendered by the browser.  A single blank line in HTML may not be shown as a blank line on the screen when the HTML is rendered.

You need to either examine the HTML source in the browser and look for the blank line.  Or else try output more significant HTML to verify the JSP scriptlets are working like:

```
<%
    out.println("<p>hello</p>");
%>
```